# How to read Key in DER format instead of PEM

Tags: openssl, pem

I am digitally signing/verifying files and in my program I am reading my keys in PEM format.

Hence, I am using the two functions `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY()` `PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey()`.

Now I want to avoid storing my keys in PEM format but rather in DER format. Which is pretty much the same, just wihtout the padding and not base64 encoded if I understood correctly.

How can I read the DER formatted keys with the API of OpenSSL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load RSA key pair without p, q, etc.. Openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829485/how-to-load-rsa-key-pair-without-p-q-etc-openssl). The answer in the question provides the source code for OpenSSL's `app.c`, which offers `load_key`. `load_key` will load a key in FORMAT_PKCS12, FORMAT_ENGINE, FORMAT_ASN1, FORMAT_PEM and FORMAT_MSBLOB. In particular, you are looking for `d2i_PrivateKey_bio` or `d2i_RSAPrivateKey_bio` and friends.